# How to get the latest backup of a database from a folder?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the full path of the latest backup in a folder.

How would I get this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `master.sys.xp_dirtree`

This code will get you the topmost file in a directory, granted your backups has dates on them. **The highest date should be the highest file in the directory file structure**.

Your final filepath for your backup will be in `@LatestBackupFilepath`

```
DECLARE @BackupDirectory NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @LatestBackupFilepath NVARCHAR(255);

SET @BackupDirectory = 'C:\YourBackupFolder'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DirectoryTree') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #DirectoryTree;

CREATE TABLE #DirectoryTree (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
      ,depth int
      ,isfile bit);

INSERT #DirectoryTree (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @BackupDirectory, 1, 1;

;With LatestBackup
AS
(
    SELECT 
        TOP 1 subdirectory AS [Filename]
    FROM 
        #DirectoryTree
    WHERE 
        isfile = 1 
        AND RIGHT(subdirectory,4) = '.BAK'
    ORDER BY 
        id
)
SELECT
    @LatestBackupFilepath = CONCAT(@BackupDirectory, '\', [Filename])
    FROM LatestBackup

DROP TABLE #DirectoryTree;
```